# complexity in terms of big O

Tags: algorithm, big-o

can anyone tell me how this is the order  so that each one is big-OH of next one.

1. √n√logn      2. 〖16〗^(log√n)    3.  n/〖(logn)〗^2      4.  √n log⁡(n^30)

Comment: Hi, I think your question is better suited for http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please state your question clearly in the text here, don't take a picture of a whiteboard scribbling that doesn't really tell us much. You might also not be at the right site, are you sure this is a programming question ?

Comment: It is algorithms and their complexity related question

Comment: Firstly, please _write out_ these questions for searchability, don't simply post a picture. Secondly, what have _you tried_? This site isn't designed to complete homework questions upon request, but rather help you understand things or solve problems you're having trouble with. Please consider revising this question :)

Comment: @nos while this question hasn't been asked well, nor formatted correctly, questions regarding the analysis of time complexities are perfectly acceptable. OP just needs to show some work and come back with a _problem_ rather than a _request_

Answer (score -1):

Correct order should be : **1-->2-->4-->3**
i.e. 1'st=O(2)=O(4)=O(3)